# Wrap a form inside a popup in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have the following form:

```
<form ng-submit="$ctrl.submit({from:$ctrl.from, to:$ctrl.to})">
    <label>From:
        <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.from">
    </label>
    <label>To:
        <input type="text" name="input" ng-model="$ctrl.to">
    </label>
        <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Apply" />
</form>
```

I was looking over the web for a way to wrap it inside a popup but didn't find anything about it.

Now the form appears all the time on the screen, what I want to do is to make it appear as a popup when it is clicked.

Is there an approach to do this?

Comment: Are you using any UI framework?

Comment: @IbraheemAl-Saady no

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is wrap your form with a div and make that div position to absolute and style however you want, and you can bind a `ng-show` to it and control the show/hide of the popup from the controller.

I created a plunk here check it out http://embed.plnkr.co/z3dXmI/
It will give you an idea, but you can style it however you want.

Also, I would recommend using a UI framework/library, something like [SemanticUI](https://semantic-ui.com/) or [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/)

Answer (score 1):

if you want it to pop-up, i suggest you need to use a UI framework like angular UI Bootstrap. here is the [link](https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/) you can also check their [sample](https://plnkr.co/edit/SMzGkv?p=preview)

```
$ctrl.openComponentModal = function () {
var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
  animation: $ctrl.animationsEnabled,
  component: 'modalComponent',
  resolve: {
    items: function () {
      return $ctrl.items;
    }
  }
});

modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
  $ctrl.selected = selectedItem;
}, function () {
  $log.info('modal-component dismissed at: ' + new Date());
});
 };
```